# Bug caused during installing genymotion emulator

Tags: software-installation

I have tried to install genymotion android emulator but I am stuck at a point after downloading the file from geny motion site.

I tried to install it from terminal by typing

```
chmod +x genymotion-2.1.1_x64.bin
```

it throws an error:

```
chmod: cannot access ‘genymotion-2.1.1_x64.bin’: No such file or directory
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: paste the output of -  `ls`

Answer (score 0):

check if your are in the right folder whwhere you have downloaded the genymotion then run the commands

```
chmod +x genymotion-2.1.1_x64.bin
```